# Move div background position on jQuery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get this to work but for some unknown reason the image isn't budging.. Check out the JSfiddle I created [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u3AM7/). (The image is supposed to jump when you hover over it and float back down when you hover off).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hover-image').hover(

    function() {
      // Over
      $(this).animate({
        'background-position': 'center top'
      }, 5000);
    },
    function() {
      // Out
      $(this).animate({
        'background-position': 'center center'
      }, 5000);
    }
  );
});
```

```css
#hover-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/artbees/paradise-fruits/256/Banana-icon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hover-image"></div>
```

EDIT: I have now found that you can't animate on non-numeric css values. Changing background position to use percentages solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot animate a non-numeric CSS property:

> The `.animate()` method allows us to create animation effects on any **numeric** CSS property.
>
> Source: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: So what if I use {'background-position-x' : '50%'} ...? Would that work?

Comment: Tried it and it actually works. Sorry I thought the code is quite simple and self explanitory,  doesn't really need a whole explination... But anyways!, you pointed me in the right direction, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

look this plugin http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html - 
A jQuery plugin that allows the position of a background image to be animated.

[i update jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3AM7/11/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hover-image').hover(

        function(){
            // Over
            $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: '50% 100%'},500);              
        },
        function(){
            // Out
            $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: '50% 50%'},500);             
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: @AndreyShatilov thank you very much, almost identical to the code I'm currently using. Much appreciated.